# phpunit replace the method return

Tags: phpunit

Here is my code. How can I modify the function's return result.

```
class Replace {
    public function add($a){
        // how can I replace $this->double($anyNum) return value
        return $a + $this->double($a);
    }
    public function double($a){
        return $a + $a;
    }
}
class ReplaceTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testadd(){
        $replace = $this->getMock('Replace');

        // I want to control the method's return, 
        //no matter what num passed to it from function add
        $replace->expects($this->any())->method('double')->will($this->returnValue(15));

        // this return null
        $data = $replace->add(6);

        // this is the expected result I want, 
        // and when I set the returnValue(21),I hope the expected result is 27
        $this->assertEquals(21, $data);
    }
}
```

How can I modify my code, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If specified, the second parameter of getMock() tells phpunit which methods to replace. Thus, in your case:

```
$replace = $this->getMock('Replace',array('add'))
```

Although in the example you gave, I'd recommend not mocking the Replace class, adding a test for the double() method will suffice, as if the double() test passes, you can rely on that method's result.

Comment: thank you. `$replace = $this->getMock('Replace',array('double'));` is correct. I use this example because I want to test `move_uploaded_file` in another class.I put `move_uploaded_file` in a public function such as `my_move_uploaded_file`, then replace `my_move_uploaded_file` function's return to let the test pass

Comment: Yeah, in this case it makes sense to stub a method on the same object.